# How to determine where a dependency is used? (Java, Maven)

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

When using Maven with Java, is it possible to see where a dependency is used? Specifically to know which classes in your project import a class from a given dependency?

This is especially difficult when the package naming of the class and the dependency declaration's tags do not line up.

For example, given a POM which contains a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

find all classes that uses it (such as):

`import org.company.similarprojectnamebutnotquitethesame.packagecontinued.SomeClass`

TLDR: Is there an efficient way to locate all files in my project that use a given dependency?

Comment: See here: http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav  and put your imported class into the field `classname`...

Comment: @khmarbaise this is great; but are there maven plugins or something that can be exact?

Comment: If you want to know which of your own classes depend on this dependency, you can simply remove it from your classpath and see which class generate errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JAR search engine that matches the class name with a package, such as [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com) or [help4j.com](http://www.help4j.com)

Comment: There can be thousands of classes contained within a dependency. You'd need to search your project for every single one. Inversely, you could do a search for every single import in your project. Either way is painful.